# Why does (6-3x)/2 fail to render here?

Tags: fractions, braces

I have the following code:

```
$$f_ {Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{f_ {X,Y}(x,y)}{f_ {X}(x)}=\left\{  \begin{array}{ll} {\displaystyle \frac{1/2}{x/2}=\frac{1}{x}}, &\text{if}~0\leq x\leq 1~\text{and}~0\leq y\leq x, \\ {\displaystyle \frac{3/2}{6−x/2}=\frac{1}{x}}, &\text{if}~1<x\leq 2~\text{and}~0\leq y\leq 2−x. \end{array}$$
```

with which I actually want to see `(6-3x)/2` in the second line of the bracket.

[image: img]

However, it fails to render if I put `(6-3x)/2` there.  I have to use this instead:

```
$$f_ {Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{f_ {X,Y}(x,y)}{f_ {X}(x)}= \   \left\{  \begin{array}{ll} \frac{1/2}{x/2}=\frac{1}{x}, &  \mbox{if $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq x$}, \\ \frac{3/2}{\frac{6−3x}{2}}=\frac{1}{x}, &  \mbox{if $1 < x \leq 2$ and $0 \leq y \leq 2−x$}. \end{array} \right.$$
```

which gives me:

[image: img2]

I would like to ask how I can achieve what I want, and why my method fails in the first place.  Thanks.

I also have problem with `2-x` not rendered properly if put in the same place.  However, this code works just fine:

```
$$f_ {Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{x}, &  \mbox{if $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq x$}, \\ \frac{1}{2−x}, &  \mbox{if $1< x\leq 2$ and $0\leq y\leq 2−x$}. \end{array} \right.$$
```

I got:

[image: img]

Why does it work when it's simple, but not in that complicated case?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What you would like is to have "(6-3x)/2" as the denominator of the fraction? The problem with the first output is only that no parentheses show up?

Comment: The problem is a non-ASCII character between `6` and `x`, which is virtually invisible.

Comment: @Vincent, thank you for the welcome.  The first output is there to show what I can get so far.  If I put `(6-3x)/2` there, nothing will render.  I am using Auto-LaTex on Google Docs.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know anything about auto-LaTeX on Google Docs but:

- The problem comes from a non-ASCII character, which is supposed to render a minus, but is not an ASCII character. With the naked eye, it is hard to distinguish it from a minus, even for a cat. One way to find these characters is to use [this tool](https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/), but there are many others. A second instance of this character occurs in `2-x`.
- If this is to go into a LaTeX document, you may want to use a more modern syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{f_ {X,Y}(x,y)}{f_ {X}(x)}=
\begin{dcases}
 \frac{1/2}{x/2}=\frac{1}{x}, &\text{if}~0\leq x\leq 1~\text{and}~0\leq y\leq x,
 \\
 \frac{3/2}{6-x/2}=\frac{1}{x}, &\text{if}~1<x\leq 2~\text{and}~0\leq y\leq 2-x. 
\end{dcases}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right about `2-x`.  It also fails to render.  How do I work around it then?

Comment: @retu Just replace the minus-like characters in your code by real minus signs, which you could copy from my code, or just type.

Comment: I use this code and it fails: `$$f_ {Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{f_ {X,Y}(x,y)}{f_ {X}(x)}=\left\{  \begin{array}{ll} {\displaystyle \frac{1/2}{x/2}=\frac{1}{x}}, &\text{if}~0\leq x\leq 1~\text{and}~0\leq y\leq x, \\ {\displaystyle \frac{3/2}{3-\frac{3x}{2}}=\frac{1}{2-x}}, &\text{if}~1<x\leq 2~\text{and}~0\leq y\leq 2−x. \end{array}$$`

Comment: @retu In `0\leq y\leq 2x` there is another strange character. Use `$$f_ {Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{f_ {X,Y}(x,y)}{f_ {X}(x)}=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} {\displaystyle \frac{1/2}{x/2}=\frac{1}{x}}, &\text{if}~0\leq x\leq 1~\text{and}~0\leq y\leq x, \\ {\displaystyle \frac{3/2}{3-\frac{3x}{2}}=\frac{1}{2-x}}, &\text{if}~1<x\leq 2~\text{and}~0\leq y\leq 2-x. \end{array}$$` (if you look very closely you realize that the minus is a bit shorter).

Comment: I saw that.  The code you give doesn't render either.  T_T

Comment: Thanks for everything tho!

Comment: @retu I missed the fact that there is missing `\right`. Use `$$f_ {Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{f_ {X,Y}(x,y)}{f_ {X}(x)}=
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} {\displaystyle \frac{1/2}{x/2}=\frac{1}{x}},
&\text{if}~0\leq x\leq 1~\text{and}~0\leq y\leq x, \\ {\displaystyle
\frac{3/2}{3-\frac{3x}{2}}=\frac{1}{2-x}}, &\text{if}~1<x\leq 2~\text{and}~0\leq
y\leq 2-x. \end{array}\right.$$`.

Comment: Buhuhuhu, that doesn't work either. T_T

Comment: @retu On my machine `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$f_ {Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{f_ {X,Y}(x,y)}{f_ {X}(x)}=
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} {\displaystyle \frac{1/2}{x/2}=\frac{1}{x}},
&\text{if}~0\leq x\leq 1~\text{and}~0\leq y\leq x, \\ {\displaystyle
\frac{3/2}{3-\frac{3x}{2}}=\frac{1}{2-x}}, &\text{if}~1<x\leq 2~\text{and}~0\leq
y\leq 2-x. \end{array}\right.$$
\end{document}` compiles but as I said I do not know anything about GoogleDoc.

Comment: Can you try it on http://mathb.in/?

Comment: @retu I am sorry, I can't.

Comment: Thanks for everything tho.  Auto-LaTeX is still the best choice for many.  The only free LaTex GDocs add-on.

Comment: I think it has to do with the memory allocation of Auto-LaTeX.  I have different long formula.  It has to be split in order to render, else it won't show.